# Does libvirt support auto memory ballooning

Tags: memory, libvirt

I have a KVM/QEMU/libvirt Arch Linux VM running on an Arch Linux host that I use for building software. I would like it to have access to 2 GiB of RAM when it is idle, but have access to 32 GiB of RAM when it is building software. With the following configuration, I can boot the machine with 2 GiB of RAM and manually inflate and deflate the memory balloon, but the `autodeflate` option does not seem to do anything.

```
<memory unit='GiB'>32</memory>
<currentMemory unit='GiB'>2</currentMemory>
<devices>
...
  <memballoon model='virtio' autodeflate='on'/>
...
</devices>
```

If the available RAM in the guest is at 2 GiB when I start compiling, it stays there, even if the host has tons of free memory. If I manually set the memory to 32 GiB in `virt-manager`, the guest gets 32 GiB, but never gives the memory back even if the guest is idle and the host needs it.